# Why is mongoose timing out when I try to add a record?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
'use strict';
const utils = require('../utils/writer.js');
const Worker = require('../models/worker');

exports.workersPOST = (body) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const worker = new Worker({
      "workerId": body.workerId,
      "name": body.name,
      "location": {
        "latitude": body.location.latitude,
        "longitude": body.location.longitude,
      },
      "home": body.home
    })
    try {
      console.log('worker=', worker)
      const response = await worker.save();
      console.log(response)
      resolve(response)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error: ' + err);
    }
  });
}
```

The line “console.log('worker=', worker)” returns:

```
worker= {
  workerId: '21882101',
  name: 'Lucy Liu',
  location: { latitude: 61.5024551, longitude: 0.1100078 },
  home: 'Berlin',
  _id: new ObjectId("623ae42b2a9e76f1e5e17120")
}
```

Then after a short pause I get the following error:

```
Error: MongooseError: Operation `workers.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
POST /v1/workers - - ms - -
```

The line 'console.log(response)' never gets called.

I have tried a version of this without using a Promise and get the same result.

The schema ('../models/worker') I use:

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    latitude: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    longitude: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
})

const workerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    workerId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    location: locationSchema,
    home: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Worker', workerSchema);
```

I’m pretty sure mongoDB is up and running as another program I use it with is working fine. Also ‘ps -ax | grep mongo’ returns the following:

```
 1916 ??         0:08.71 /Users/saul.rickman/.homebrew/opt/mongodb-community/bin/mongod --config /Users/saul.rickman/.homebrew/etc/mongod.conf
17570 ttys001    0:00.00 grep mongo
 8890 ttys002    0:00.33 node /Users/saul.rickman/myProjects/rest-api-with-mongodb/node_modules/.bin/nodemon app.js
```

(BTW, I get much the same result when I try to read the DB with a find command.)

Comment: Have you tried making a separate schema model for your latitude and longitude?

Comment: I've changed the schema as suggested and edited it into my OP. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that the record is being saved?

Comment: I have no idea. TBH, this is my first experience with mongodb/mongoose.

Comment: Download MongoDBCompas, https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass and put in your MongoDB compass URI from the website, and see if it added the value to your database. Im thinking the value has never been added due to schema errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing but...
Nothing was happening because I'd neglected to connect to my database. The following code sorted the problem:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost/WorkerDBex';
mongoose.connect(url);
```